# Creating A Program That terminates After X Amount times

Tags: python, pydev

I am working on a calculator program that asks a user for their input to execute a program the problem is I only want the program to loop as many times as the value of their input. Unfortunately for me the program just continues to loop. How can I fix it so that it only runs x amount of times as the user inputs?

```
 loop=1
choice=0  
while loop == 1:
    print("Welcome to Calculator Function!")
    n =input("How many operations do you want to do?: ")
    for n in xrange(6):
                print("Your options are:")
                print(" ")
                print("1) Addition")
                print("2) Subtraction") 
                print("3) Multiplication")
                print("4) Division")
                print("5) Quit CalculatorFunction.py")
                print(" ")

                choice = input("Choose your option: ")
                if choice == 1:
                    add1 = input("Add what: ")
                    add2 = input("To what: ")
                    print add1, "+", add2, "=", add1+add2
                elif choice == 2:
                    sub2 = input("Subtract what: ")
                    sub1 = input("From what: ")
                    print sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1-sub2
                elif choice == 3:
                    mult1 = input("Multiply what: ")
                    mult2 = input("To what: ")
                    print mult1, "*", mult2, "=", mult1*mult2
                elif choice == 4:
                    div2= input("Divide what: ")
                    div1= input("From what: ")
                    print div1, "/", div2, "=", div1/div2
                elif choice == 5:
                    loop = 0
                    print"Thank you for using CalculatorFunction.py have a good day!" 
                else:
                    print"No selection made, please try again."
    return[n() for n in xrange(6)]
```

Comment: Well for one thing you immediately reassign `n`, so what's the point in taking user input?

Comment: is this in a function or is that a randomly placed return statement?

Comment: I saw an example of a question that seemed similar although it was for rolling die, and they placed return at the end of the function @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Where did I reassign n? @jonrsharpe

Comment: you can only return inside a function you need to break out of the loop with a `break` statement, you could just use a for loop in the range of `n` without the while loop.

Comment: @StackXchangeT on the very next line: `for n in xrange(6):` sets it to zero.

Comment: Ah so the return function needs to be indented in other words correct? I thought having a for loop like that would require a while statement.@PadraicCunningham

Comment: I had no idea that I did that, I will try to remember not to make a simple mistake like that again @jonrsharpe

Comment: @StackXchangeT, the return statement can only be used if you are using the code in a function, if you are put it where the break is.

Comment: It works the way I want it to work with the return statement thank you for all of your valuable input. Now I am off to create more programs like this! @PadraicCunningham

Comment: No worries, enjoy your programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop in range of `n` and break outside that loop

```
choice = 0
while True: # while True will keep going until we break
    print("Welcome to Calculator Function!")
    n = input("How many operations do you want to do?: ")
    for _ in xrange(n): # how many times user want to use the calc
            print("Your options are:")
            print(" ")
            print("1) Addition")
            print("2) Subtraction")
            print("3) Multiplication")
            print("4) Division")
            print("5) Quit CalculatorFunction.py")
            print(" ")

            choice = input("Choose your option: ")
            if choice == 1:
                add1 = input("Add what: ")
                add2 = input("To what: ")
                print add1, "+", add2, "=", add1+add2
            elif choice == 2:
                sub2 = input("Subtract what: ")
                sub1 = input("From what: ")
                print sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1-sub2
            elif choice == 3:
                mult1 = input("Multiply what: ")
                mult2 = input("To what: ")
                print mult1, "*", mult2, "=", mult1*mult2
            elif choice == 4:
                div2= input("Divide what: ")
                div1= input("From what: ")
                print div1, "/", div2, "=", div1/div2
            elif choice == 5:
                loop = 0
                print"Thank you for using CalculatorFunction.py have a good day!"
            else:
                print"No selection made, please try again."
    break # end after "n" loops
```

Or just loop in range of input `n` without the while:

```
loop=1
choice=0

print("Welcome to Calculator Function!")
n = input("How many operations do you want to do?: ")
for _ in xrange(n):
        print("Your options are:")
        print(" ")
        print("1) Addition")
        print("2) Subtraction")
        print("3) Multiplication")
        print("4) Division")
        print("5) Quit CalculatorFunction.py")
        print(" ")
```

Comment: By the way when I changed my for loop the variable "i" comes up as an unused variable should I add a _i to let python know it is not used?

Comment: I will change it to _